# Installing New relic disables php excel download

Tags: php, phpexcel, newrelic

I have new relic installed and it causing download file(XSLS) not to work. if disable new relic  my download button works.

I am also get following header 
Request Method:POST
Status Code:303 See Other

What might be causing it.

Comment: Which do you have loading first? Try reversing the order and testing again. Does either Relic  or PHP Excel have a no-conflict parameter. You might need to namespace them in order to avoid conflicts in classes loading.

Comment: @Difster we have name space for  PHP Excel. Using drupal enviroment